# error when inserting data into database when multiple sms is sent

Tags: android, sms

I have designed my own compose screen for sending sms,
in that when send button is clicked
I am sending msg to multiple recepients

```
 sendBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    avedPhoneno = "5558,5554,5556";

                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedPhoneno, ",");
                    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {

                        tempMobileNumber = (String) st.nextElement();
                        System.out.println("tempMobileNumber in onclicklistener "+tempMobileNumber);
                        if (tempMobileNumber.length() > 0
                                && encryptedText.toString().trim().length() > 0) {


                            sendSMS(tempMobileNumber,
                                    base64msgString.concat(timeStamp1));

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
```

and the method for sending sms is

```
 private void sendSMS(String edittextSmsNumber, String msg) {


                PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);
                PendingIntent DeliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                // short port = 8888;

                sms.sendTextMessage(edittextSmsNumber, null, msg, sentPI, DeliveredPI);
        }
```

and in the broadcast reciever i am trying to store the data into database

```
private BroadcastReceiver sendreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
     {
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
             {
                     String info = "Send information: ";

                     switch(getResultCode())
                     {
                             case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                 info += "send successful";
                                 smsSent = true;
                             if (senderinfo != null && timeStamp != 0 && msgString != null) {
                                System.out.println("entered into database");
                                System.out.println("tempMobileNumber is "
                                        + tempMobileNumber);
                                outboxDatabase.open();
                                outboxDatabase.insertintoOutbox(msgString, key,
                                        tempMobileNumber, timeStamp);
                                outboxDatabase.close();
                            }
                            //unregisterReceiver(this);


                            break;
                             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                 info += "send failed, generic failure";
                                 break;
                             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE: 
                                 info += "send failed, no service"; 
                                 break;
                             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                 info += "send failed, null pdu"; 
                                 break;
                             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF: 
                                 info += "send failed, radio is off";
                                 break;
                     }

                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }
     };
```

but I am able to store the last number i.e., 5556 only in the database thrice.

I want to store all the three numbers into the database.
I want to store when only the msg is sent properly

i.e., when  `getResultCode() = Activity.RESULT_OK;`
able to send to the three numbers but only not able to store in the database
how to overcome this.

Comment: Iam able to make it out we have to add flags PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA and also pass the data using intent.putExtra